# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, random-variables, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, random-matrices

Let random matrix $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{C^{\mathrm{m} \times \mathrm{n}}}$ and random vector $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{C^{\mathrm{m} \times 1}}$ are unknown distributed, but their covariance and correlation are known, $\mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{X}}$, $\mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{y}}$, and $\mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{Xy}}$. The question is whether there is any bound for the following expression, (like Cauchy-Schwarz or Jensen's)

$?\le \mathbb{E}[(\mathbf{X}^{\mathrm{H}} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\mathrm{H}} \mathbf{y}] \le ?$

Also I have to mention, $\le$ here means an element-wise inequality since corresponding expectation is an $\mathrm{n} \times 1$ vector.